# ASP.NET @Register vs. @Reference

Tags: asp.net, page-directives

I'm working with referencing user controls on my ASPX page and I'm wondering what the difference is between these two page directives.

[@Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w70c655a.aspx)
[@Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`@Register` is the more commonly used directive.  You use this when you want to use a user control in your aspx or ascx page declaratively.  `@Register` associates the control with a specific prefix and you can then use it in your markup.

`@Reference` only tells ASP.NET to compile the other control when your aspx or ascx page is compiled.  That makes sure it is available at run-time and can be added to your control hierarchy programmatically.  This is less common since dynamically changing user controls at runtime is not comon.

Here's a good blog post about it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/johnkatsiotis/archive/2008/08/13/the-reference-directive.aspx

Answer (score 24):

`@Register` is primarily used for registering **tag prefixes** to *declaratively* use controls within a page.

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="my" namespace="MyNamespace" %>

<my:CustomControl runat=server />
```

`@Reference` is primarily used to refer to a page or user control (by file name or virtual path) to *programatically* refer to **members** of the page or control.

```
<%@ Reference Control="MyControl.ascx" %>

<%  MyControl ctrl = (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
    ctrl.CustomProperty = "..."; //REFERENCE directive is needed to access property
%>
```